# Как реализовать закрывающееся уведомление на всех страницах?

Tags: php, javascript, opencart, уведомления

Имеется сайт на котором в header размещён блок с текстом
**Пример:**
[image: Notification]
Как реализовать скрытие (при использовании кнопки закрытия .close, оно меняет свойство блока на display: none) этого блока на всех страницах?

OpenCart 2.3.0.2 / OcStore

```css
.notification-block {
    border: 1px solid #fa1f81;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 70%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
.notification-text {
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #fa1f81;
}
.close {
    position: absolute;
    right: 2%;
    top: 28%;
    opacity: 0.7;
    color: #fa1f81;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="notification-block">  
    <p class="notification-text">Приглашаем к сотрудничеству салоны и оптовых покупателей</p>
    <i class="fa fa-times-circle-o close" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: Когда срабатывает событие на `.close` вам надо просто в куку записать статус этого уведомления. **Например:** изначально у вашего окна `display: none;`. Скрипт смотрит, есть ли кука `notify1`, если нет - показываем это окно (`display: block;`), если есть, то ничего не делаем (окошко видно не будет). А при закрытии `$('.close').click()` вы создаем куку `notify1`.

Comment: @Manitikyl, совершенно забыл, реализовал данный скрипт в ответе.
Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Реализовал данный вопрос через cookie запрос.

```
https://jsfiddle.net/dragunov_m/y9wbpjrd/
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    var visit=GetCookie("notification-close");
    if (visit==null){
        cookiebar();
    }

    function setAgreeCookie() {
        var expire=new Date();
        expire=new Date(expire.getTime()+7776000000);
        document.cookie="notification-close=here; expires="+expire;
    }

    $('#close-notification').click(function(){
        setAgreeCookie();
        $('#notification').addClass('close-cookies');
    });

});

function GetCookie(name) {
    var arg=name+"=";
    var arglen=arg.length;
    var dclen=document.cookie.length;
    var i=0;

    while (i<dclen) {
        var j=i+arglen;
        if (document.cookie.substring(i,j)==arg)
            return "here";
        i=document.cookie.indexOf(" ",i)+1;
        if (i==0)
            break;
    }
    return null;
}

function cookiebar() {
    $('#notification').addClass('display');
}
```

```css
#notification {
    display: none;
}

#notification-block {
    border: 1px solid #fa1f81;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    padding: 5px 0;
    width: 50%;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 10px !important;
}

#notification-block p {
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
    font-size: 14px;
}

#close-notification {
    position: absolute;
    right: 1%;
    top: 27%;
    color: #fa1f81;
}

#notification.display {
    display: block;
}

.close-cookies {
    height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="notification">
  <div id="notification-block">
    <p>Приглашаем к сотрудничеству салоны и оптовых покупателей</p>
    <a href="#" id="close-notification" class="fa fa-times-circle-o">     </a>
  </div>
</div>
```